# Loop and display json data

Tags: javascript, json

How do I loop the json data and display using **qtip**?

```
 elements: {
    "nodes": [
            {
            "data": {
                "id": "a2345",
                "name" : "b1234"
                "type": "test", 
                }
            },
            {
            "data": {
                "id": "a212",
                "name" : "c34"
                "description": "hellooo", 
                }
            },
     ],
     },
});


cy.nodes().qtip({
    content:function(){     
            return ' id: '+ this.data('id') 
            +' name: '+ this.data('name')  
            + ' type: '+ this.data('type') 
            + ' description: '+ this.data('description')
    },

});
```

Current output:

> node1 - id: a2345, name: b1234, type: test, description: undefined
>
> node2-  id: a212, name : c34, type: undefined, description: hellooo

Expected output:

> node1 - id: a2345, name: b1234, type: test
>
> node2 -  id: a212, name :c34, description: hellooo

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: So what do you want in case, if **type** doesn't exist or you just want to use any blank string or any other static string in this case? Explain please?

Comment: I have edited the code and added the expected output. As you can see that the code is displaying all the data (including the undefine ones). I just want to remove the undefined fields and display the required data. (as shown in expected output).

Comment: Okay, one last question. The the object referred by `data` key will only have `id`, `name` & any one from `description` & `type`, right?

Comment: Yea, you can loop through the object referred by **data** key using `for(var key in this.data){}` and construct the string to be returned. In this case, the order of elements will be different, so if first time, if it returned `node1 - id: a2345, name: b1234, type: test` then second time it may return `node2 - name :c34, description: hellooo, id: a212`. The reason is: iterating over the keys of an object doesn't preserve order. If you are ok then I can suggest you one solution otherwise I will need to go for other solution ( that I don't think better).

Comment: sure I would appreciate your suggestion. Thank you

Comment: Okay I got one solution. If that's the case that **id**, **name** are fixed. Then we can iterate over remaining keys after deleting these fixed **key:value** from object. I think this would be better as you do not want **if-else**. I am updating my answer with a pure js example separately. If it still doesn't work please comment back.

Comment: okay thank you so much

Comment: **@Averill**, I have updated my answer. Please check it. As I had mentioned in my comment before. First, I have presented my idea using simple pure JavaScript based example. Finally, I used that idea to update your code. I think, it will work. Please comment if it still doesn't work. I will try my best to help you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**@Averill**, let me start with a simple pure JavaScript based code example that will print the strings that you expect.

Here I have shown how will you construct the strings to be returned. Finally I have updated the part of your code.

#### Sample code example (JS):

```
var arr = [
        {
        "data": {
            "id": "a2345",
            "name" : "b1234",
            "type": "test", 
            }
        },
        {
        "data": {
            "id": "a212",
            "name" : "c34",
            "description": "hellooo", 
            }
        },
]

var i = 1;
for(var obj of arr) { // iterating over arr
   var data = obj["data"]; // data object
   var string = "node" + i + " - id: " + data["id"]+ ", name: " + data["name"]

    // Deleting values with fixed keys
   delete data["id"]
   delete data["name"]

    for(var key in data) { // iterating over remaining eys
       string += ", " + key + ": " + data[key];
    }

   console.log(string);
   i += 1;
}
```

#### Output:

```
node1 - id: a2345, name: b1234, type: test
node2 - id: a212, name: c34, description: hellooo
```

Now, have a look at the below code based on above code example.

> Please comment if the below code sample doesn't satisfy your problem. I will check and update it.

```
  // You have edited your code from this point
      var i = 1;
      cy.nodes().qtip({
          content:function(){  
            var string;
            if(this._private["index"] == undefined){
              this._private["index"] = i;
              string = "Node" + i + " - " + "id: "+ this.data("id")+ ", name: " + this.data("name")
              i += 1
            } else {
              string = "Node" + this._private["index"] + " - " + "id: "+ this.data("id")+ ", name: " + this.data("name")
            }

            // Deleting values with fixed keys
            delete this.data("id")
            delete this.data("name")

            console.log(this.data)
            console.log(this._private.data)
            console.log(this)
            for(var key in this._private.data) { // iterating over remaining keys
              string += ", " + key + ": " + this.data(key)
            }


            return string
          },

        style: {
          classes: 'qtip-bootstrap',
        }, 
      });
```

Check the below screeshots.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have encountered some problems, the error message says that "Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined".

Comment: @ Rishikesh, So I have tried this content: function(data){ and the data displayed but I'm still facing some issues with the undefined. I have uploaded a screenshot above.

Comment: Can you please paste your code so that I could look into it or create any gist and send the link. I am unable to see any image here. And why are you using ` content: function(data){` syntax. Previously you were fetching using ` content: function(){` syntax. And refer fields using `this.data('key')` syntax. It's clear in my answer's 2nd code example. Please try and let me know if it does not work with screenshot and sample code (place somewhere on Internet and share the link)

Comment: alright I'll try it again. The solution you provide works but the qtip tooltip doesn't show up so I was trying to fix it.

Comment: Okay, well. If you face any problem. Please paste the link of tutorial for **qtip** so that I could look into it. I don't know anything about **qtip()** but I know JavaScript and I can help you.

Comment: I still encounter problem with the displaying. Here's the link: https://jsfiddle.net/9v7c3ju2/7/#&togetherjs=yuB1Kfiw4n

Comment: **@Averill**, I have updated my code and also added 2 screenshots. I have also created one gist at https://gist.github.com/hygull/94bab5ee591c70e0a855a34f3b2f59e9. You can copy and paste it in any HTML file and test it in your browser.
I am using Google Chrome and here it shows somewhat expected results. I think you should try it once then we'll move further.

Comment: yes this is the result I hope to achieve. I'll try to work on it. Thanks for your help. Also, may I ask what is "this._private", why can't we use "this.data" instead?  I'm confused with it.

Comment: **@Averill**, I printed **this.data** on console and got this information. You can also check it in browser's console. Create a simple html file and paste the code from my gist and see the result. **this.data** has lot many properties, so it's better to check before using any object.

Comment: I have added 3rd screenshot that shows the items of **this.data** where you can see **_private** key.I have highlighted data also.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation and screenshot. Really appreciate your efforts. @Rishikesh

Comment: No problem **@Averill**. Thanks to you too as you tried and responed positively. Enjoy programming.